# Read data frame from get_prediction function of statsmodels library

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, statsmodels, arima

I am creating forecast model using arima here i have use statsmodels

Get forecast steps ahead in future

```
pred_uc = results.get_prediction(start='2001-05-01',end='2002-05-01')
print(pred_uc)
```

When I print this i get its in objects can it be converted into readable format in array or data frame

```
<statsmodels.tsa.statespace.mlemodel.PredictionResultsWrapper object at 0x00000000156E71D0>
```

Here it looks like data is stored in memory location and since i am noob in python i need a bit of help here...

[code from](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/a-guide-to-time-series-forecasting-with-arima-in-python-3)

[Source code of statsmodels library](http://www.statsmodels.org/devel/_modules/statsmodels/tsa/arima_model.html#ARIMAResults)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this [Google search result (Japanese)](https://momonoki2017.blogspot.ca/2018/03/python10.html), try

```
pred_uc.predicted_mean
```

You can also get a DataFrame of 95% confidence intervals with

```
pred_uc_ci = pred_uc.conf_int(alpha=0.05)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
pred_uc = fitted_model.get_prediction(start='2001-05-01', end='2002-05-01')
pred_uc = pred_uc.predicted_mean
pred_uc.columns = ['predicted1','predicted2', 'predicted_n']
pred_uc.head()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).